# How to add an image as a bullet point in a specific WordPress widget?

Tags: widgets, css

I am using a widget to show latest tweets in my blog. The widget shows latest tweets as a list item. The default list bullet point (black square bullet point) of the theme is shown. I want to change the bullet point to a custom image or symbol (for example, a small twitter bird picture). 
How can I do this specifically for that particular widget? 
PS. The widget directory does not contain any CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your theme's CSS, which you can get access at `Appearance > Editor` in the Dashboard.

You will need to style the widget list element by dropping this in your theme's style.css

```
.widget.latest-tweets .widget-wrap ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: url(http://your-image-url-here);
}
```

Comment: Form the page source, I find this information "<div id="latest-tweets-2" class="widget latest-tweets"><div class="widget-wrap"><h4 class="widgettitle">Twitter tweets</h4>" about the widget.